# window.open can't attach params to a url ends with .html

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, browser, frontend

while I'm using

> window.open('/a.html?title=666')

there is no title = 666 in the new window's url

but

> window.open('/a?title=666')

works fine.

it's really confused me.

by the way, I'm using node's 'serve' npm package to test in localhost.

during the research of documents, it is supposed to be the same.

Comment: Should probably use `./a.html?=title=666`. Works for me. What does `location.search` print in the opened `window`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on macOS 14 with Chrome 122

Answer (score 1):

I got why.
The npm package 'serve' says:

cleanUrls (Boolean|Array)

> By default, all .html files can be accessed without their extension.
>
> If one of these extensions is used at the end of a filename, it will
> automatically perform a redirect with status code 301 to the same
> path, but with the extension dropped.